# A characterization of the module function on a locally compact division ring

Tags: measure-theory, algebraic-number-theory, topological-groups

[The same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449889/a-characterization-of-the-module-function-on-a-locally-compact-division-ring) was asked in Math StackExchange about 3 months ago.
Since nobody has answered to it, I would like to post it here.

References:

Weil's Basic Number Theory(denoted by **BNT**).

Bourbaki's Commutative Algebra(denoted by **BCA**).

Let $K$ be a topological ring with an identity.
Suppose every non-zero element of $K$ is invertible.
Let $K^* = K - \{0\}$ be the multipilcative group of $K$
If the map $x \rightarrow x^{-1}$ is continuous on $K^*$, we say $K$ is a topological division ring.
Suppose the topological space $K$ is non-discrete, Hausdorff and locally compact.
Then we say, by abuse of terminology,  $K$ is a locally compact division ring.

Let $K$ be a locally compact division ring.
Then the aditive group $K$ is a locally compact group.
Hence there exists a Haar measure $\mu$ on $K$.
Let $a$ be an element of $K^*$.
Then the map $x \rightarrow ax$ is an automorphism of the locally compact group $K$.
Hence the map $X \rightarrow \mu(aX)$ defines an invariant measure on $K$ where $X$ is any measurable subset of $K$.
Therefore there exists a constant $c \gt 0$ such that $\mu(aX) = c\mu(X)$ for every measurable subset $X$ such that $0 \lt \mu(X) \lt \infty$.
We denote $c$ by $mod(a)$.
We define $mod(0) = 0$.

$mod(a)$ can also be defined by the map $x \rightarrow xa$(see **BNT** or **BCA**).

Clearly $mod(ab) = mod(a)mod(b)$ for all $a, b \in K$.
The function $mod$ is continuous(see **BNT** or **BCA**).
The subset $\{x \in K|\ mod(x) \le d\}$ is compact for every real number $d \gt 0$(see **BNT**).

Locally compact division rings are classified as follows(see **BNT** or **BCA**).

1. The field of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$.
2. The field of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$.
3. The field of Hamilton's quaternions $\mathbb{H}$.
4. Finite division algebras over the field of $p$-adic numbers.
5. Finite division algebras over the field of formal Laurent series over a finite field.

Here is my question.
Is the following proposition true?

**Proposition**
Let $K$ be a locally compact division ring.
Let $\phi$ be a real valued function defined on $K$.
Suppose $\phi$ satisies the following conditons.

1. $\phi$ is continuous.
2. $\phi(x) \gt 0$ for all $x \neq 0$ and $\phi(0) = 0$.
3. $\phi(xy) = \phi(x)\phi(y)$ for all $x, y$.

Then there exists a real number $c \gt 0$ such that $\phi(x) = mod(x)^c$ for all $x$.

**Remark**
Let $K$ be a locally compact division ring.
Let $x \in K^*$.

1. If $K = \mathbb{R}$, then $mod(x) = |x|$.
2. If $K = \mathbb{C}$, then $mod(x) = |x|^2$.
3. If $K = \mathbb{H}$, then $mod(x) = |x|^4$.
4. If $K = \mathbb{Q}_p$, then $mod(x) = |x|_p$ where $|x|_p$ is the canonical absolute value, i.e. $|p|_p = 1/p$.

Comment: I have given an answer over at MSE. The basic idea is to take advantage of the compactness of the kernel of the modulus function on $K^\ast$, and the fact that compact subgroups of $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ are trivial. I would prefer to keep the discussion there for now, in view of recent meta discussions.

Answer (score 2):

This is true (assuming as you do implicitly that all your division rings are nondiscrete). The reason is that for any nondiscrete locally compact division ring $\mathbf{K}$, the multiplicative group $\mathbf{K}^*$ of $\mathbf{K}$ has a unique maximal compact subgroup (namely the elements of modulus 1) and the quotient is either isomorphic to $\mathbf{R}$ (Archimedean case) or to $\mathbf{Z}$ (non-Archimedean case). Therefore $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbf{K}^*,\mathbf{R})$ is 1-dimensional, so all continuous homomorphisms from $\mathbf{K}^*$ to $\mathbf{R}$ are proportional. Multiplicatively, this means that every continuous homomorphism $f:\mathbf{K}^*\to\mathbf{R}_{>0}$ has the form $f(x)=\mathrm{mod}(x)^c$ for some $c\in\mathbf{R}$. If you require in addition that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$, then necessarily $c>0$.